# Delete Row From Gridview with CommandName

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete Rows from my `Gridview` using a `CommandName` but its not working.  I am using get `RowIndex` to do this.

I do not get any errors, it just doesn't do anything when I click on the `ImageButton`.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="538px" BackColor="White"  BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Small"  >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" Width="16px" CommandName="DeleteRow" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="30px" />
            <ItemStyle Height="10px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is cs code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("DeleteRow"))
        {
            GridViewRow oItem = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            int RowIndex = oItem.RowIndex;
            GridView1.DeleteRow(RowIndex);
            DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [do not post duplicate code / questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156371/delete-row-from-gridview1/27156460?noredirect=1#comment42807100_27156460)

Comment: Isn't it the same you asked about 25 minutes ago?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156371/delete-row-from-gridview1/27156689#27156689

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156371/delete-row-from-gridview1/27156460?noredirect=1#comment42807100_27156460

Comment: I tried to delete that question but failed

Comment: also why are you checking `IsPostBaack` in your event does the Clicking of the LinkButton cause a postback to trigger..? if you are not sure then the `if(IsPostBack)` check in your `Page_Load` and see if it hits the code.. also look at the opposite check `if(!IsPostBack(){}` read up on the difference between `calling Bind on your object which is `gridview1.Bind()` and the calling of the `DataBind()` method this will drive you nuts if you do not understand the when and how.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

Instead of Doing what you did I will suggest you to Delete from DataBase and Again Bind the GridView

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{



    if (e.CommandName.Equals("DeleteRow"))
    {
        GridViewRow oItem = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        int RowIndex = oItem.RowIndex;

        girdivewBind(); // Bind your gridview again. 
    }

}


public void deleteRecord(string ID)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
   {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Mytable where ID=@id";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
        con.Open();
        var temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I can't delete it from the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**GridView:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton CommandName="DeleteProduct" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"    " ImageUrl="~/Admin/Images/SendToShop.png"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**C#**

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteProduct")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = grdCart.Rows[index];

            int productId = int.Parse(((Label)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lbProdId")).Text);

            DeleteProduct(productId);
       }
    }

private void DeleteProduct (int productID)
    {
        //delete the product
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the row from database as well and reflect the changes on the page then use `GridViewID_RowCommand`

aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged"
CssClass="mGrid"
PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" >

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
     Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"
    CommandName="DeleteRow" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
        {
           int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
           GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[index];
           string id = selectedRow.Cells[0].Text; //assuming your ID is the first column of your grid
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString); //assuming your connection string is in web.config
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM myTable where id='" + id + "'", con);
           sq.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
        }

    }
```

In case you do not remember the column index of your `ID` still you can get the `ID` value by the name of the `Grid Header` [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716160/2374691)

In your pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.IsPostBack)
       { 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable",con);
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
     }
   }
```

EDIT: grids shouldn't be bind on `PostBack`, I recommend do not do this. Update the gridview not in `Page_Load`, instead wrap your `GridView` inside an `UpdatePanel`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
              <ContentTemplate>

  <asp:GridView ID="gv1" ...> ... </asp:GridView>

                 </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then call `UpdatePanel2.Update()` wherever you need to update your Grid (in this case you'll need to `Bind` the grid where you are modifying its source i.e `RowCommand` and after binding call `UpdatePanel2.Update()`)

Remember whatever you do, you can not stop the `PostBack` because the click is on the button.

Answer (score 0):

I have done row deliting in Gridview at runtime without delete record in datatable. Please find the code below.

My GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAddEditDefectParameterDetails" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grdAddEditDefectParameterDetails_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdAddEditDefectParameterDetails_RowDeleting" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DEFECT_PARAM_CODE" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headTb4" Visible="false"
        HeaderText="Defect No.">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headTb4" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Select">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="ACTIVE"
                onclick="javascript:return OnChange(this);" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="idDefectParam" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DEFECT_PARAM_CODE") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="5%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DEFECT_PARAM_DESCRIPTION" ItemStyle-Width="44%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headTb4"
        HeaderText="Defect Parameter Description" HtmlEncode="false">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Penalty Applicable" HeaderStyle-Width="7%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headTb4">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkPenalty" Enabled="false" runat="server" DataTextField="PENALTY_APPLICABLE"></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="7%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headTb4" HeaderText="Defect Weightage" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDefectWeightage" runat="server" CssClass="inputSmallGrid"
                MaxLength="6" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumericKey(event);" Text="0.00"
                AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="7%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

In your .cs file add following function

```
protected void grdAddEditDefectParameterDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

After that wright the following code to delete the row

```
grdAddEditDefectParameterDetails.DeleteRow(grdAddEditDefectParameterDetails.Rows[i].RowIndex);
```